# Programmatically accessing themes/styles/attrs in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, apk

I'd like to access complex resources ("bag resources") compiled into my apk.  For example, getting all the attributes of the current theme, preferably as an xml I can traverse.

Themes/styles can be accessed using obtainStyledAttributes() but it requires knowing the attributes in advance.  Is there a way to get a list of the attributes that exist in a style?

For example, in a theme like this:

```
<style name="BrowserTheme" parent="@android:Theme.Black">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#FFFFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

how can I access the items without knowing their names in advance?

Another example would be attrs.xml, where some attributes have enums or flags, such as this:

```
<attr name="configChanges">
    <flag name="mcc" value="0x00000001" />
    <flag name="mnc" value="0x00000002" />
    ...
</attr>
```

How can an application get these flags without knowing their name?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(...)`, `Resources.obtainTypedArray(int)` can be used to access all the attributes for a style, without having to specify which attributes you are interested in.

You can then access the elements of the TypedArray to find the resource id/types/values of each attribute.

```
TypedArray array = getResources().obtainTypedArray(
    R.style.NameOfStyle);

  for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); ++i) {

    TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
    array.getValue(i, value);

    int id = value.resourceId;

    switch (value.type) {
      case TypedValue.TYPE_INT_COLOR_ARGB4:
        // process color.
        break;

      // handle other types
    }
  }
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but `value.resourceId` seems to be the same as `array.getResourceId(int, int)` - that is, it's the source of the value, not the `R.attr` code for the style field. A constant value will have a `resourceId` of 0; a value like `"@string/foo"` will have `R.string.foo`.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a better way, but you can always access the 'raw' XML using [getXml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getXml(int))

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I tried that first, but apparently "bag" resources are not recognized as xml.  It failed with an error, about the resource being a bag resource rather than an xml resource.